# Problema para retornar un entero de un arreglo

Tags: java

deseo construir el método darElemento mayor que retorna el mayor elemento del arreglo, a partir de una muestra ordenada descendentemente por algoritmo burbuja.

Cree el método darElementoMayor() que retorna el número mayor de la muestra. Debe utilizar obligatoriamente el método del punto anterior para cumplir con el requerimiento.

```
    public int darElementoMayor()
{

   return array[0].ordenarBurbujaDescendente();

}
```

El método del punto anterior que exije usar es el siguiente:

```
 public MuestraOrdenada ordenarBurbujaDescendente()
{
    int[] array=darCopiaValores();

        for(int  i=0;i<tamanio;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<tamanio-1; j++)
            {
                if (array[j]<array[j+1])
                {
                    int temp= array[j];
                    array[j]=array[j+1];
                    array[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    return new MuestraOrdenada (array);
}
```

LA CLASE MuestraOrdebnada es la siguiente:

```
    public class MuestraOrdenada
{


    private int valores[];


    public MuestraOrdenada( int[] vals )
    {
        valores = vals;
        verificarInvariante( );
    }


    public int darTamanio( )
    {
        return valores.length;
    }


    public int[] darCopiaValores( )
    {
        int[] copiaValores = new int[valores.length];
        for( int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++ )
        {
            copiaValores[ i ] = valores[ i ];
        }
        return copiaValores;
    }


    public int contarOcurrencias( int valor )
    {
        int ocurrencias = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < valores.length && valores[ i ] <= valor; i++ )
        {
            if( valores[ i ] == valor )
                ocurrencias++;
        }
        return ocurrencias;
    }


    public int contarValoresDistintos( )
    {
        int valoresDistintos = 1;
        int ultimoValor = valores[ 0 ];
        for( int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++ )
        {
            if( valores[ i ] != ultimoValor )
            {
                ultimoValor = valores[ i ];
                valoresDistintos++;
            }
        }
        return valoresDistintos;
    }


    public int contarElementosEnRango( int inf, int sup )
    {
        int numElementos = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < valores.length && valores[ i ] <= sup; i++ )
        {
            if( valores[ i ] >= inf )
                numElementos++;
        }
        return numElementos;
    }


    public int darValorMasFrecuente( )
    {
        int valorMasFrecuente = -1;
        int numeroAparicionesMasFrecuente = 0;

        int valorActual = -1;
        int numeroAparicionesNumeroActual = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++ )
        {
            if( valores[ i ] != valorActual )
            {
                if( numeroAparicionesNumeroActual > numeroAparicionesMasFrecuente )
                {
                    numeroAparicionesMasFrecuente = numeroAparicionesNumeroActual;
                    valorMasFrecuente = valorActual;
                }
                valorActual = valores[ i ];
                numeroAparicionesNumeroActual = 0;
            }
            numeroAparicionesNumeroActual++;
        }
        // Contar las apariciones del último numero
        if( numeroAparicionesNumeroActual > numeroAparicionesMasFrecuente )
        {
            numeroAparicionesMasFrecuente = numeroAparicionesNumeroActual;
            valorMasFrecuente = valorActual;
        }
        return valorMasFrecuente;
    }


    public boolean buscarBinario( int valor )
    {
        boolean encontre = false;
        int inicio = 0;
        int fin = valores.length - 1;
        while( inicio <= fin && !encontre )
        {
            int medio = ( inicio + fin ) / 2;
            if( valores[ medio ] == valor )
            {
                encontre = true;
            }
            else if( valores[ medio ] > valor )
            {
                fin = medio - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                inicio = medio + 1;
            }
        }
        return encontre;
    }


    private void verificarInvariante( )
    {
        assert valores != null : "El arreglo de valores no puede ser null";
        assert valores.length > 0 : "Debe haber por lo menos un valor";
        // Verificar que los valores estén ordenados
        for( int i = 1; i < valores.length; i++ )
        {
            assert valores[ i - 1 ] <= valores[ i ] : "Los valores deben estar ordenados";
        }
    }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda lo agradeceré mucho,he tenido problemas para conseguir entender este método.

Comment: Tiene un a clase MuestraOrdenada, puede colocar el código?

Comment: ya añadí la clase MuestraOrdenada

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes agregar un método a la clase `MuestraOrdenada` de forma que retorne o el arreglo de números, o un indice del arreglo,

```
public class MuestrOrdena(){
  private int valores[];

  ... //todo lo demás igual

  public int darUnValorDeUnaPosicionSolicitada(int posicion){
    return this.valores[posicion]; //ojo validar que la posición exista
  }

  public int[] getValores(){
    return this.valores;
  }

}
```

y en el método

```
public int darElementoMayor()
{

   return ordenarBurbujaDescendente().darUnValorDeUnaPosicionSolicitada(0);

  //o como alternativa ordenarBurbujaDescendente().getValores()[0];

}
```